# How can I determine if a row is visible in my collection after filtering?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to figure out how to determine if an item in my collection is visible in the grid after filtering? I'd like to update the following `UpdateIf` code for only those records showing:

`UpdateIf( Nominations, true, { Status: {Value: "Approved"}, 'Approved By': varUser } );`

It seems straightforward, but I simply can't find the answer. Thank you very much!

I've tried the following code without success:

`Filter(MyCollection, Visible = true)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same conditions you used for filtering collection instead of `true` in the `UpdateIf` function.

For example: Update all list items with ID greater than 5

Use formula like below:

```
UpdateIf(
   Nominations,
   ID > 5,
   {
       Status: { Value: "Approved" },
       'Approved By': varUser
   }
);
```

Similarly, you can add multiple conditions as per your requirements like:

```
UpdateIf(
   Nominations,
   ID > 5 && ID < 15,
   {
       Status: { Value: "Approved" },
       'Approved By': varUser
   }
);
```

---

**OR** you can use formula like below to update records which are available in the collection:

```
ForAll(
    MyCollection,
    Patch(
        Nominations,
        LookUp(Nominations, ID = ThisRecord.ID),
        {
            Status: { Value: "Approved" },
            'Approved By': varUser
        }
    )
)
```

Make sure you are passing values for all required columns in the list with correct data types.